# Solving $\sin z = i$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I know that

$$\sin z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

so:

$$\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} = i\implies e^{iz}-e^{-iz} = -2$$
but I can't take anything useful from here. How do I solve such equations?

What about $\tan z = 1$? Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $x=e^{iz}$, we then are solving for $x$ that satisfy
$$x-1/x+2=0$$
Multiplying by $x$ gives
$$x^2+2x-1=0$$
Which means
$$x=-1\pm\sqrt{2}$$
Thus we have that
$$e^{iz}=-1\pm\sqrt{2}$$
and
$$z=\frac{\ln(-1\pm\sqrt{2})}{i}=-i\ln(-1\pm\sqrt{2})$$
Then for your question about $\tan(z)=1$, that is easy. This occurs whenever $\sin(z)=\cos(z)$, implying $z=\frac{\pi}{4}+2n\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: +1 Of course, other branches of the logarithm yield other solutions coinciding with the periodicity of the sine function.

Comment: but how do I know there are no complex solution for $\sin z = \cos z$?

Answer (score 1):

using $z=a+ib$ we get

$$ \sin(z)=\sin(a)\cos(ib)+\cos(a)\sin(ib)\\
=\sin(a)\cosh(b)+i\cos(a)\sinh(b)  $$

so we can split the equation into real and imaginary parts to yeild two real equations ...

$$ \sin(a)\cosh(b)=0 \\
\cos(a)\sinh(b) =1
$$

since $\cosh(b)$ is never zero, the only solutions to the firset equation are

$$ a=n\pi$$

for any integer $n$.

Now use $\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n$ to get

$$ b=\sinh^{-1}((-1)^n)   $$

following the first answer we can get

$$ \sinh^{-1}((-1)^n) = \ln(\sqrt2+(-1)^n)   $$

So the final answer ends up being ...
$$z=n\pi+ i\ln(\sqrt2+(-1)^n)\\ =n\pi+i(-1)^n\ln(1+\sqrt2)   $$

Answer (score 0):

How about multiplying both sides with $e^{iz}$ then variable substitution and solve a regular second degree polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin z = \cos z $ comes down to ..

$$ e^{iz}-e^{-iz}  = i( e^{iz} + e^{-iz} )  $$

$$  (1-i)e^{iz}= (1+i)e^{-iz} $$

$$  e^{2iz}= \frac{ 1+i}{1-i} =i=e^{i( \frac\pi2+2n\pi )}$$

So $$z=\frac\pi4 +n\pi$$

All solutions are real.